# how to use if condition to check if function argument is TRUE in R

Tags: r

There is my function code

```
fun(arg1){
    if(arg1 == 'ggwp'){
        new.fun1()
    }
}


>fun(ggwp)
>Error in fun(ggwp): object 'ggwp' not found.
```

i don't know how to use if condition that make arg1 = str, then run a new function in R. It is different from C. There is error when I  try this code. So, how do I make it work?

Comment: Do you mean `fun('ggwp')` ?

Comment: no, not with single quote here.

Comment: @GaryZhang - well, you are getting an error that `ggwp` doesn't exist.

Comment: Single quotes and double quotes are treated the same way in R. In either case, your condition is testing whether or not `arg1` is equal to the string `"ggwp"`. But in your test you are passing a bare object name that is undefined. As @RonakShah said, you want to have `fun('ggwp')` or equivalently, `fun("ggwp")`.

Comment: if I want to use fun(ggwp), I should change if condition to if(arg1 == ggwp). Is that right? @dshkol